# Autofac Single Instance with event handlers

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a cache class that is registered as a single instance with Autofac. Whenever I clear the cache I call the method `ExecuteCacheCleared();`

The cache class looks like this

```
public IEnumerable<ICacheCleared> _cacheCleared { get; private set; }

public CacheService(IEnumerable<ICacheCleared> cacheCleared) : ICacheService
{
    _cacheCleared = cacheCleared;
}

private void ExecuteCacheCleared()
{
    if (_cacheCleared != null)
    {
        foreach (var cacheCleared in _cacheCleared)
        {
            cacheCleared.EntityCacheChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I then have several concrete implementations of ICacheCleared that are called when ExecuteCacheCleared is called.

So currently I am registering bits in autofac as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<CacheService>().As<ICacheService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CacheCleared>().As<ICacheCleared>().InstancePerRequest();
```

With the above, I get an error (which I get) because the SingleInstance won't work with the InstancePerRequest but in my CacheCleared concrete class i also inject other dependencies that need to be InstancePerRequest.

Hopefully, you can see what I am trying to achieve (basically trying to notify subscribing classes of changes) but I'm stuck on how to achieve this.

Comment: When `ExecuteCacheCleared` is called on the singleton, you want every `ICacheCleared` that has been resolved from the container to be "pinged" through `EntityCacheChanged()`, is that correct?

Comment: @MarcL.- Yes! that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not be possible by taking a dependency on `IEnumerable<>`. That relationship type is intended for supporting [multiple implementations of a service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b), not for resolving all instances.

I don't know of any way to do what you're trying to do OOTB. It's a fairly esoteric and difficult scenario. The best way I can think of is to invert the control: require your `ICachedCleared` implementations to take a dependency on `ICacheService`. In turn, give `ICacheService` a method like `AddNotifier(ICacheCleared)` which could be called from the constructor (if it's cheap--I highly suggest making it cheap) or on first use (if it's expensive--e.g., returns a `Task`).

`AddNotifier()` would add each to a collection which would then be called from `ExecuteCacheCleared()`.

This is going to be pretty complex, because you're going to have to be VERY careful with this code in a multi-threaded environment--which you are surely in, since you're using `InstancePerRequest()`. Also, you're going to have to figure out a way of *removing* all those instances when the request has completed (use a collection of [`WeakReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)? Make `ICacheCleared` implement `IDisposable` and call a `ICacheService.Remove()` when disposed?). And probably many other issues I haven't considered.

The complexity of this is high enough that you may want to take a moment and reconsider the design itself before you head down the rabbit-hole.

Good luck!

Comment: I marked this as correct not because of the suggested work around but for the last sentence "take a moment and reconsider the design" which i think is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what the intention of your design is. I'm using autofac and have caches which are instanced per request and others which are single instanced.  Generally requests should be short lived, anything cached per request should be a snapshot at the time of the request.

Data we cache per request is generally done to avoid reloading or recalculating of data within the one request. It's dubious that you have a requirement to clear a cache instanced per request, even more dubious that you want to clear these caches across all the current requests, I don't understand how or why you would have a need for such functionality.

Anyhow, I think the answer could be very simple.  **ICacheService** also needs to be **InstancePerRequest** or **ICacheCleared** needs to be single instanced.

Alternatively you should break up the design of your caches such that you separate the caches instanced per request from those which are single instanced.  i.e. have a **ICacheService** which has a collection of **ICacheCleared** and a **IRequestCacheService** which has a collection of **IRequestCacheCleared** objects.

You can inject single instanced objects into objects instanced per request but not vice versa.  So if you like the **IRequestCacheService** could also be injected with the **ICacheService** and call **ExecuteCacheCleared** on the **ICacheService** when **ExecuteCacheCleared** is called on the **IRequestCacheService**.